# Lopsided planet

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, equilibrium, geophysics

Something that has always puzzled me about [Pangaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea).

If we have a "roughly" spherical mass of solids, aren't two points on opposite sides **approximately** the same distance from the center of gravity?

If so, how can there be a kilometer or more of ocean above one of them, without it flowing to make the ocean surface the same distance from the center of gravity all around?

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/how-high-can-a-mountain-possibly-get doesn't seem to address this, since it is talking about a specific peak rather than a wide-spread lopsidedness.

Comment: Does it make sense for ocean to flow upwards?

Comment: This post seems to be a version of [_How tall can mountains be on a planet?_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_mountains_in_the_Solar_System)

Comment: Is it flowing upwards if the land is closer to the center than the water?

Comment: @Qmechanic, The link goes to Wikipedia.  I don't find an SE question with that exact title, but the one I did find and cite isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the definition of a planet is an object which is large enough to form itself into a sphere (without igniting fusion). That is, gravity can cause a hot interior to flow. Then “sea level” becomes an equipotential surface.

Answer (score 0):

They're not. Otherwise it would all be covered in a (slightly shallower) layer of water. Where the continent is, the crust is thicker. Also probably around the continent there is slightly more water, as the landmasses have a gravity of their own: A good example are glaciers. If a glacier melts, the sea-level rises on the opposite side of the world, because the glacier's gravity stops pulling the water away.

Comment: They're not even "approximately" the same distance?  I wouldn't expect a thicker crust to make that big a difference.  And the difference it would make would be to move the center of gravity _further_ from the ocean on the opposite side.

Comment: They are "approximately", but there's also not that much water there. So if the water level (= distance from center of gravity) is equal all around the oceans, then these slight height differences make a difference.